# How can i code ItemCommand and OnDeleteCommand From a DataGrid inside a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I'm have 3 controls inside the repeater namely label,button and a datagrid.
I have written click event for the button.
but i dont know how to write code to the Datagrid onitemcommand and ondeletecommand.

Here is my code goes:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeaterSearchResult_ItemDataBound" ID="repeaterSearchResult">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="textBoxSearch"  ForeColor="White" width="25%" runat="server" 
              Text="<%#Container.DataItem%>"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="BTNAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"  OnClick="button_click"/>
         <br />
         <asp:DataGrid ID="dgLCL" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ShowFooter="FALSE" CellPadding="3" OnItemCommand="dgLCL_Select" 
              OnDeleteCommand="dgLCL_Delete">
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="GrossUOMType" HeaderText="Type">
              </asp:BoundColumn>
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Volume" HeaderText="Volume">
              </asp:BoundColumn>
              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="DELETE">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNDelete" 
                        ImageUrl="~/AppImages/grid-icon-delete.jpg"
                        ToolTip="Delete"  CommandName="DeleteItem" 
                        OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmDelete();"
                        AlternateText="Delete" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>
              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Add">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="IMGBTNAdd" 
                           ImageUrl="~/AppImages/grid-icon-add.jpg"
                           ToolTip="Insert"  CommandName="InsertItem" 
                           AlternateText="Insert" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>
          </Columns>
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White" 
                    Mode="NumericPages">
        </PagerStyle>
                                                </asp:DataGrid><br />
```

Here is my code behind:

```
 protected void repeaterSearchResult_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
      string Flag = Session["Flag"].ToString();
      if (Flag=="B") 
      {
            e.Item.FindControl("textBoxSearch").Visible = false;
            e.Item.FindControl("BTNAdd").Visible = false;
      }
      DataGrid gv = e.Item.FindControl("dgLCL") as DataGrid;
      //TextBox textBox = e.Item.FindControl("textBoxSearch") as TextBox;
      Label label = e.Item.FindControl("textBoxSearch") as Label;
      // BindGrid(textBox.Text,Session["Flag"].ToString());

      string SFRID = label.Text;
      if (Flag == "L")
      {
         sql = "Select MasterNo , MasterDate,GrossWt,GrossUOMType,Volume from 
                 VW_TransLCLMaster  where tBLG_NUIsActive=1 and PortOfDischargeName='" 
                 + SFRID + "'";
         //mobjGenlib.objDBLib.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds);
         if (gv != null)
         {
             gv.DataSource = ds;
             gv.DataBind();
         }
       }
  }
```

Question is:

I have select ,delete and insert button in the Datagrid.I want to know how to code to onitem and ondelete command.

Can any one pls help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this find your datagrid in repeater_ItemDataBound

```
DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)e.Item.FindControl("dgLCL");
```

than fire the event you want, if you want `onitemcommand`
than write in the next line

```
 dg.ItemCommand +=
```

and press tab two times event will be handled in code behind. and the code formed is something like

```
    dg.ItemCommand += new DataGridItemCommandEventHandler(dg_ItemCommand)
}
void dg_ItemCommand(object sender, DataGridItemCommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick replay let me give try of your solution